# Mysql Select Max Consecutive Records (with gaps)

Tags: mysql, select, count, max

I'm having trouble selecting consecutive records and I think I've pin pointed the problem. I'm thinking it was something to do with a jump in the id field.

I have set up some sample data here:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fqSixe8TBPu7s7Ko22ySmr/0

Basically, I am using the following code to return a players max consecutive wins:

```
set @player=0, @count=0;
select max(@count := if(outcome = 2 and player = 785, @count+1, 0))
from cc6_MensLeague_rounds use index(maxcon);
```

The result in the above sample data is 13 (it's supposed to be 24).

It works fine with most players but I get unexpected results with a select few. After digging around I noticed that it could possibly be a jump in the id fields of certain records. I need to ignore the gaps somehow.

If anyone has a solution, or can point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you go with 1 and 2, rather than the more conventional 0 and 1?

Comment: Incidentally, you could illustrate this problem as effectively with a dozen rows, instead of 1000. :-(

Comment: Hi Strawberry, I just dumped the data into db-fiddle.com for simplicity reasons so that I'm working with the exact same data from my DB. As for using 1 and 2 instead of 0 and 1. I'm somewhat new to MySQL and when i initially made the DB It wasn't really thinking of it at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query seems to work for me:

```
SET @count=0;

SELECT max(@count := if(outcome = 2, @count+1, 0)) AS MAX_CONSECUTIVE_WINS
FROM 
 (SELECT *
  FROM cc6_MensLeague_rounds
  WHERE player = 785
  ORDER BY date ASC) AS Temp
```

Let me know if it doesn't always work :)

Comment: Perfect... absolute genius :-) Would you care to take it one step further? I have the following sample data https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/35EQE2yzdxNs3KHZnQkMuQ/1 and I'd like to make the 785 dynamic. I've tried the following code `select max(@count := if(outcome = 2, @count+1, 0)) as max_consecutive_wins from (select * from cc6_MensLeague_rounds where player = id order by date asc) as temp` with a result of 1 and I also tried `... where player = cc6_MensLeague_players.id ...` with a result of Unknown column in 'where clause' Is there a way to pass the player id to this query?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by making the 785 dynamic? Do you want to get the result for all players, or do you just want to make the 785 variable?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was trying to say. I figured it out though. Thanks a million for your help.